# Trying to send email through GoDaddy using Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

Here is the code I am using to send email through GoDaddy:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpout.secureserver.net', 465)
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("username", "password")
msg = "Please work!!!!!!"
fromaddr = "fromemail"
toaddr = "toemail"
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg)
```

When running the script, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "emailTest.py", line 3, in <module>
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpout.secureserver.net', 465)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py",      line 250, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 311, in connect
(code, msg) = self.getreply()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 362, in getreply
raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I'm really lost on this one, and I know for a fact that my login information is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace these two lines:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpout.secureserver.net', 465)
server.starttls()
```

with these two:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtpout.secureserver.net', 465)
#server.starttls()
```

Quoting [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL):

> > SMTP_SSL should be used for situations where SSL is required from the beginning of the connection and using starttls() is not appropriate.

Using port 465 is one of those situations. `SMTP.starttls()` is appropriate when you use port 25 or port 587.

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS
- https://www.fastmail.fm/help/technical/ssltlsstarttls.html

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a strange error on GoDaddy's side now though...

I get an email from `Mail Delivery System` with the error: `[Return Code 550] sid: Xtpe1o00e3l0Tyx01 :: 5.7.1 more information. ye4si18523263pbb.103 - gsmtp` in my GoDaddy inbox.

Comment: That's a new issue. Either 1) create a new question for it, or 2) update this question with your new information.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is having problems with RFC 5322 compliant emails this ended up working for me:

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg.set_unixfrom('author')
msg['From'] = 'you@mail.com'
msg['To'] = 'them@mail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple email in python'
message = 'here is the email'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtpout.secureserver.net', 465)
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login('yourgodaddy@mail.com', 'PASSWORD')

mailserver.sendmail('you@mail.com','them@mail.com',msg.as_string())

mailserver.quit()
```

Comment: Kudos for this! You just saved me a lot of mucking around debugging an issue.

Comment: Replace lines 2 & 3 with from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart &
from email.mime.text import MIMEText as @TBone pointed out.  After that this solution worked great :)

Answer (score 2):

Joe's code worked for me.  The only thing i had to change were the import statements:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
```

Then everything worked!  Thanks, Joe.

(Sorry I couldn't leave this as a comment or upvote it - my reputation isn't high enough to comment yet.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the overall code that works.

```
import smtplib`enter code here`
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg.set_unixfrom('author')
msg['From'] = 'your email'
msg['To'] = 'xyz@mail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple email in python'
message = 'here is the email'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtpout.secureserver.net', 465)
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login('your email', 'password')
response = mailserver.sendmail('from@mail.com','to@mail.com',msg.as_string())
mailserver.quit()
```

Comment: +Sanjeev can i send multiple emails before closing the mailserver.quit().
Also, the sent emails are not showing up in the Sent Items folder.